# Doctrine INDEX BY fails when using a joined field in grouped query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm very sorry for the form of this question, but I honestly don't know which part of my query is causing the error. My DQL:

```
SELECT t.id, count(DISTINCT u.id) AS employee_count 
FROM ACME\MyBundle\Entity\User u 
INDEX BY t.id 
INNER JOIN u.teams t 
WHERE u.manager = :manager 
GROUP BY t.id
```

Execution of this query yields an error:

```
[Semantical Error] line x, col y near 't WHERE u.manager': Error: 't' is already defined.
```

If I remove the `INDEX BY` clause it works as expected (apart from the indexing of course).

Is there a way to get the indexing to work in such case? I can loop this manually, but It would add much overhead for large amounts of data.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is that you are aliasing `u.teams` with `t` where `t` is already assigned to something else.

Comment: I pasted the whole DQL (only changing the names of the tables and the bundle) so you can see the alias is declared only once.